# How can I link boost library on cluster?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cluster-computing

I have program which works well on my computer with following command

```
g++ -o result source.cpp -lboost_program_options
```

However, this command doesn't work on the cluster where the boost library is such

```
 #%Module1.0#####################################################################
##
## boost modulefile
##
## boost/1.55.0/gcc-4.4.7
##
proc ModulesHelp { } {
      puts stderr "\tThis module loads boost-1.55.0 environment for aries compute nodes."
      puts stderr ""
      puts stderr "\tBuild script:    /build/gcc-4.4.7/build-boost-1.55.0.sh"
      puts stderr "\tCompilation options:  /build/gcc-4.4.7/BUILD-boost-1.55.0/boost/bbost.v2/config.log"
}
module-whatis   "loads the boost environment for x86_E5v2 CNs"

module load  mvapich2/2.0.1/gcc-4.4.7 python/2.7.9/gcc-4.4.7
conflict boost

# for Tcl script use only
set             version         1.55.0
set             root            /ssoft/boost/1.55.0/RH6/gcc-4.4.7/x86_E5v2/mvapich2

setenv BOOST_ROOT       "${root}"
setenv BOOST_INCLUDE    "${root}/include"
setenv BOOST_LIBRARY    "${root}/lib"
prepend-path    LD_LIBRARY_PATH "${root}/lib"
```

I have searched how to solve this problem for a while, but haven't found one works for me.

Thank you.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: fatal error: boost/program_options.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/program_options.hpp>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the path to where the compiler can find the include files and libraries, since they're installed in a non-default path.

Most likely something like this, *after* loading the module for boost (that's "minus capital i" for include files and "minus capital L" for libraries):

`g++ -o result source.cpp -I$BOOST_INCLUDE -L$BOOST_LIBRARY -lboost_program_options`

Alternatively, you can update the `$CPATH` and `$LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables (actually, the module file should probably be doing that for you):

```
export CPATH=$BOOST_INCLUDE:$PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=$BOOST_LIBRARY:$LIBRARY_PATH
g++ -o result source.cpp -lboost_program_options
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It compiles now. I was trying to link something like $LD_BOOST_LIBRARY.

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot.